# Halt the execution when something is written to stderr

Tags: bash, signals, error-handling, interrupt, stderr

I have trouble with error handling in bash scripts. None of the solutions I have seen for error handling in bash seem to work so far for this example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

eval $(do_stuff)
touch file
```

Output is:

```
./script.sh: line 4: do_stuff: command not found
```

But even then it happily continues and creates the file, which is what I want to forbid. I figured I can pipe stderr to another program and terminate the whole thing when it grabs some output:

```
unbuffer ./script.sh 2>&1|{ while read stdin; do echo $stdin;killall -9 bash;done; }
```

Nevertheless, it works roughly only 5% of the time. In most cases it doesn't manage to kill the script early enough.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `eval` ?  That's "masking" the failed exit code and causing a "success" to be returned to the script, allowing it to continue.

Comment: What appears in the body of the script isn't on me, it's written by other developers and this is one use case which caused a fatal error in our system. I want to prevent that in a future.

Comment: So what would stop the next developer doing `eval "something_wrong 2>/dev/null"` ?

Comment: That would mean intentional harm. I would like to prevent stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to elegantly handle the case I posted:

```
eval() {
    if [[ -z "${@}" ]];then
        exit 1
    fi
    builtin eval "$@"
}
```

It overrides default eval() implementation and exits if it receives no input. I'm not accepting this answer though, because it still doesn't answer the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change it to assignment first, then eval.

Example 1 (halt if input command invalid):

```
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ cat h2.sh
#!/bin/bash

trap err_handler ERR
err_handler() { echo trapped ; exit; }
e2=$(echoasasas)
eval "$e2"
echo "next"
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ sh h2.sh
h2.sh: line 5: echoasasas: command not found
trapped
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$
```

Example 2 (halt if output is not a valid command):

```
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ cat h2.sh
#!/bin/bash

trap err_handler ERR
err_handler() { echo trapped ; exit; }
e2=$(echo xxxxx)
eval "$e2"
echo "next"
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ sh h2.sh
h2.sh: line 6: xxxxx: command not found
trapped
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$
```

Example 3 (continue run next command):

```
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ cat h2.sh
#!/bin/bash

trap err_handler ERR
err_handler() { echo trapped ; exit; }
e2=$(echo ls)
eval "$e2"
echo "next"
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ sh h2.sh
Android  CRITICAL  Documents
next
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$
```

Example 4 (half if STDERR triggered in another shell):

```
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ cat /tmp/so.sh 
ls yyyyyy 2>/tmp/kas
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ cat /tmp/kas
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ cat h2.sh
#!/bin/bash

trap err_handler ERR
err_handler() { echo trapped ; exit; }
echo "before"
e2=$(/bin/bash /tmp/so.sh)
eval "$e2"
echo "next"
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ sh h2.sh
before
trapped
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$ cat /tmp/kas
ls: cannot access 'yyyyyy': No such file or directory
[xiaobai@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: My bad, the above will not works if STDERR happen in the halfway of `/bin/bash /tmp/so.sh`